# Can someone help avatar rendering for ejabberd / xmpp servers?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, vcf-vcard

We are building a mobile only chat application for one industry at a time (let's say Chem.) then replicate for other industries like Auto etc. We are utilizing ejabberd / xmpp but facing a snag of showing avatars for those, who join the industry chat room; can some expert, who has implemented ejabberd / xmpp give us an idea what and how to tinker server side settings in ejabberd / xmpp or point us in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about avatars in XMPP, you need to tell which XMPP extensions you are expecting to support: PEP based avatars ? VCard based avatar ?

In all cases, avatar in XMPP are intended to allow to display picture of your own contacts. The idea of MUC is that it proxy and anonymise you to other users (non admin) for privacy reason. You can find more details in [XMPP Academy #2 video at 34m15s](https://youtu.be/SbpFgdryyIA?t=34m15s).

However, you can easily extend XMPP to add information about avatar in your MUC presence packets or messages.